# Why do objects disappear when I zoom on a dynamic map service?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, map-service, dynamic-layer

I have a dynamic web map service that contains some point objects.
When I zoom in and out, some of the point object disappear and reappear randomly.
The map service is dynamic, no cache has been created for it.
Do you have any hint on what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure that no scale dependent visibility has been set on the layer?

Comment: @Devdatta I'm sure 100%

Comment: @yo_haha I'm closing this as too localized, there's not enough information here to work with. Please feel free to add detail, for instance how to (possibly) reproduce or a public example, and ask for it to be [re-opened](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not pre-rendered data, is there a possibility you have reached the maximum amount of displayed geometries/features?

See this thread for more information on how to set the maximum:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/17522-Cannot-add-Layer-with-more-than-500-Features

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Dynamic Layers do not have this limit. The entire image is created on the server, and no features are sent to the client.

Comment: ah, excuse me! I was under the impression you were servering (vector) features, rather than images. In that case there should be no limit.

Comment: Maybe you could provide more information. Another possibility is a choice of what to view or not, as is often used for displaying labels.

Comment: I have the same behaviour on ArcMap!!!! So I guess this is not a map service problem.
The data behaving in that way is data coming from a join between a feature layer and a Oracle View.
All data is stored in Oracle.

Comment: And I have about 60 000 lines that the join has to process. Could it be due to that?